# Trouble implementing IUserStore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I would like to make use of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, but without `EntityFramework` - I'm trying to use my own implementation of `IUserStore`. I haven't decided what database to use, but I think it's immaterial for this question.

Relevant classes, as stripped down as possible:

*Startup.cs:*

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddUserStore<CustomUserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
            .AddUserManager<CustomUserManager>();
    }
```

*ApplicationUser:*

```
public class ApplicationUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

*CustomUserStore:*

```
public class CustomUserStore<TUser> : IUserStore<TUser> where TUser : ApplicationUser
{
    private bool _disposed;

    public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        //Trying to hit a breakpoint here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //Other method implementations removed for brevity

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

*CustomUserManager:*

```
 public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors,services,logger)
    {

    }

    public override async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        // Trying to hit a breakpoint here
        return await this.Store.CreateAsync(user, new CancellationToken());
    }
}
```

*ExampleController:*

```
[Route("api/example")]
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    private CustomUserManager _userManager;
    public ExampleController(CustomUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [Route("test")]
    public void Test()
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "something", Email = "somthingElse" };
        _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "password");
    }
}
```

When I hit the URL I'm using to test it out: `api/example/test`, the constructor in `CustomUserManager` gets hit, but not `CreateAsync` in `CustomUserManager`, and thus nothing is hit in `CustomUserStore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the `CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)` method in your `CustomUserManager` but in your `Test()` method you are calling the `CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)` method.

You're calling the wrong method.

Comment: Good spot. Silly mistake.